# help with regex needed

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for which:

the string is alphanumeric and have exactly 6 characters in the first half followed by hyphen(optional) followed by optional 4 characters:(cannot have more than 4 characters in the second half)

so  any of the following is valid

```
11111A
111111-1
111111-yy
yyyyy-989
yyyyyy-9090
```

i thought this expression `/[a-zA-Z0-9]([-])?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}$/;` should work but i m unable to get it working correctly.

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: You said "exactly 6 characters in the first half", but later say that "yyyyy-989" is valid.  Am I missing something, or are these contradictory?

Comment: When asking questions about regexes, it is better to indicate the targeted languages/system. Perl's RE engine is different from JavaScript one, distinct of Java one, etc. And support in editors (or tools like grep) can vary greatly too.
Charles Stewart added the PCRE tag but I am not sure that's what you want/need.

Answer (score 5):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Comment: @tanascius: \w isn't synonym of [a-zA-Z0-9], it might include other characters like underscore _

Comment: @user268375: Notepad++ seems to use Scintilla regex engine which is very primitive, it doesn't understand {n} for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}$
```

This isn't as concise as some of the others, but it is bulletproof. Tanascius' and Streetpc's solutions will match `______-____`, since `\w` matches underscores.

One question: you say the dash is optional and the following four characters are optional, so does that mean `111111AAAA` should match? If so, my regex above is for you, since Tanascius' will not match this.

If this isn't the case, then you'll want this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Which makes use of slightly more efficient backreferenceless grouping.

One last thing. This solution won't match `111111-` but will match `11111-A`. If you would like to match on `111111-`, but also **don't** want to match `111111A`, go with this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4})?$
```

**EDIT:** Tanascius' solution no longer uses `\w`, so disregard what's said above concerning this.

Comment: Yeah, I am learning :) +1 for the *optional dash*, that is indeed not specified correctly

Answer (score 0):

If your first 6 and last 4 are alphanumeric only:

```
^\w{6}-?\w{0,4}$
```

**Note**: `\w` is a handy shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but it allows underscores (`_`). If you don't want those, just replace it with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

**UPDATE**

Two way of avoiding zeros:

1. Spliting your group, if you know that the last figure (for example) must not be 0

   `^\w{5}[a-zA-Z1-9]-?\w{0,3}[a-zA-Z1-9]$`
2. [Negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), very powerful but not available in all regex "flavours" (implementation):

   `^(?!0{6})\w{6}-?(?!0+$)\w{0,4}$`

   Those "zero-width" assertion don't consume characters, they only check what's ahead and cause the match to fail if the pattern is encountered (in the case of a *negative* look-ahead). The first one is easy enough, checking if we have exactly six 0s. The second one checks if there is one or more (`+`) 0s immediately before the end (`$`) of the line/string.

Comment: they can be only digits or can be alphanumberic too

Comment: alphanumeric means letters or digits. `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: what if i want to add another condition stating that the first half or/and second half cannot have all zeros?
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Might be off-topic, but since I am no regex expert at all I often use the txt2regex program which helps building them from textual menus. http://txt2regex.sourceforge.net.

Cannot resist to quote this: "A programmer had a problem. He realised he could solve it using a regular expression. Now he has two problems."